# Como usar o mesmo header do Bootstrap para dois menus diferentes

Tags: css

Possuo em minha página um `header` da biblioteca `bootstrap` e nele estou usando dois menus mas com as mesmas chamadas, ao redimensionar a página são exibidos dois ícones mas sempre chama os dois menus, gostaria que fosse chamado cada menu independente, tentei fazer as alterações mudando os nomes das chamadas mas o resultado não foi o esperado, tentei fazer isso em uma das tentativas:

```
.navbar-default-2 {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border-color: #e7e7e7;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-default-2 .navbar-brand {
  color: #777777;
}
```

A página em desenvolvimento é essa:
[Acesso ao projeto](http://ancestofados.com.br/anc/)

Creio estar alterando algo no lugar errado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa sua dúvida está ligada ao JS e não ao CSS.
O modo para resolver isso seria definindo um 'nome' para cada menu.

Por exemplo:

```
<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#one">
<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#two">
```

E na definição dele:

```
<div id="one" class="nav-collapse">
    <!-- resto do primeiro menu aqui -->
</div>
<div id="two" class="nav-collapse">
    <!-- resto do segundo menu aqui -->
</div>
```

Assim você determina qual deles deseja abrir, com um determinado botão.

Link demonstrando o funcionamento: https://jsfiddle.net/sz7j8fLo/2/

Comment: Fantástico, obrigado @CelsomTrindade sua ajuda foi primordial, ficou perfeito a solução indicada, mais uma vez obrigado.

Comment: Que isso. Fico feliz em ajudar.